# How can i make a c# program to know if a year is worldcup or Olympic games

Tags: c#, leap-year

So i want to make a program that knows if a year is a worldcup or olympic games, any other year will come out as "nothing". And i want to make the years between like 2000-2100 .

```
Console.Write("Please enter a year between 2000-2100: ");

int year;
            Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out year);
            Console.WriteLine("You wrote : " + year);

If (year%4 == 0 )
{
Console.WriteLine("World cup");
}
else if (year%4 == 0)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Olympic games");
}
```

I've gotten it this far, but i can't make the program know the difference between worldcup and olympic games.

---

I'l give you guys an example. I'm pretty new to programming. 
Olympic Games are every 4 years eg. 2000, 2004, 2008, 2012, 2016, etc. If the year is evenly divisible by 4 then it is an Olympic year. The Soccer World Cup is an even year between two Olympics eg. 2002, 2006, 2010, 2014, 2018 etc. That is if the year is even and not an Olympic year then it is the soccer world cup. Every other year will give the text "Nothing special this year"

Like 2003 " Nothing special this year " 
2004 " Olympic year " 
2006 " world cup "

---

```
using System;

namespace TEST 
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Write a year between 1950-2050: ");
            int year;
            Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out year);
            Console.WriteLine("You wrote: " + year);
            if (year < 1950)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1950-2050 not under");
            }

            else if (year > 2050)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1950-2050 not over");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

This is the code that works so far.

Comment: Well what are the determining factors? As it stands your if and your elseif have the same condition so thats not likely to work.

Comment: How do you decide if year is a Olympic or world cup year?

Comment: When posting code, you should post your *actual* code. This won't compile simply because C# is case sensitive and there is no such thing as `If`.

Comment: Also, are you looking *only* for summer Olympics, or winter as well? There's also no code here to print out "nothing", so you should add that as well.

Comment: `else if (year % 4 == 2)`? If you want `2002, 2006, 2010, 2014, 2018, 2022...` years

Comment: Thank you so much Dmitry ! That's what i was looking for.

Comment: Also, how do i make it so any other year other than the world cup and olympic come out as "nothing"

Comment: You add `else Console.WriteLine("nothing");`

Answer (score 0):

The 1st FIFA World Cup of the XXI century was in 2002. You need to add 2 before getting the remainder.

```
if ((year+2)%4 == 0 )
{
Console.WriteLine("FIFA World Cup and Winter Olympics");
}
```

Comment: Couldn't he just do `year % 4 == 2` instead?